# Ring of Integers of fields

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K\subset L$ be fields. Does it follow that $O_K\subset O_L$?

It seems to me that this is certainly true but I can't be too sure. I know that since $K\subset L$, then $|L:K|\geq2$. How else can I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The definition of $x$ being a member of $O_K$ is: first, $x\in K$; second, (something independent of $K$). Since $x\in K$ implies $x\in L$, it is automatically true that $x\in O_K$ implies $x\in O_L$.

Comment: Just wondering, is $O_K$ an ideal of $O_L$?

Comment: It's probably not closed under multiplication by elements of $L$.